# java.sql.ResultSet no puede ser convertido a javax.resource.cci.ResultSet

Tags: java

Hola tengo un problema en la linea rs=ps.executeQuery(); me dice que java.sql.ResultSet no puede ser convertido a javax.resource.cci.ResultSet, se supone que esto lista las imagenes que estan alojadas en una base de datos(Mysql).

```
public class personadad {
        conexion cn = new conexion();
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;

        public List listar(){

            List<persona>lista=new ArrayList<>();
            String sql="select * from persona";
            try{

                con=cn.getConnection();
                ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);


                rs=ps.executeQuery();//dice que java.sql.ResultSet no puede ser 
                                      //convertido a javax.resource.cci.ResultSet

                while (rs.next()) {
                   persona p=new persona();
                   p.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                   p.setNom(rs.getString(2));
                   p.setFoto(rs.getBinaryStream(3));
                   lista.add(p);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            } 
            return lista;
        }
```

Comment: Muestra por favor los `import` que tienes en esa clase. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, mira estos son los que tengo: 
1) import java.io.*;

2) import java.util.*;

3)import java.sql.Connection;

4)import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

5)import javax.resource.cci.ResultSet;

6)import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

Comment: El problema es que estás importando otra clase o interfaz `ResultSet` aquí: `import javax.resource.cci.ResultSet;`. Si borras esa línea y pones **`import java.sql.ResultSet;`** el error debería desaparecer.

Comment: Perfecto A. Cedano, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente ese es el error, nuevamente infinitas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás importando otra clase o interfaz ResultSet aquí:

```
import javax.resource.cci.ResultSet;
```

El error debería desaparecer si borras esa línea y pones esta:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

A veces hay clases que se llaman igual según los paquetes por lo que hay cuidar siempre de hacer la importanción correcta para evitar este tipo de problemas.